# Want CSS columns to overlap

Tags: css

I've searched through Stackoverflow and found plenty of people trying to avoid overlapping in CSS columns, but I'm actually being asked to make text and images overlap.

UPDATE:

Better image explaining what I've been asked to do, and a link to the code I'm using. Thanks!

[image]

<sup>http://unfetteredletters.com/webdev/twocolumnlayout.jpg</sup>

Link to code:
http://unfetteredletters.com/webdev/AF_columnLayout/AF_2columnLayout.html

Is this possible?

Comment: Short answer: Yes :P How - What have you tried?

Comment: Can you put this in a jsfiddle instead of a jpegimage? That will give us something to work with. B.t.w. the text and images don's actually overlap in your image. Is that what you meant, or is the image false?

Comment: I've tried just a basic 2 column layout so far, but wasn't sure if it was at all possible to have text and images from one column overlap into the other column. (The image is just something I threw together in Photoshop.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with negative margins.

Check out this: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

```
#content {margin-right:-100px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes it is possible.

To answer the question you did not ask, you could make the images background-images.

Comment: you dont need fixed positioning for this just margins! this is the correct answer.

Comment: the images in this case are clearly par of the content. Background images are no content but styling. From a semantic point to view this method should be considered wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the containing block of your images and divs css property for display are relative. then set the children you want to overlap display property as absolute. now you can position them with right and left top or bottom with the appropriate pixels. but you really need to provide your css style so that it's easy to give an answer you can use.

Comment: Thanks so much to everyone for responding.

I'm including a link to the code I'm using, as well as a new image better explaining what I've been asked to do.

http://unfetteredletters.com/webdev/twocolumnlayout.jpg

http://unfetteredletters.com/webdev/AF_columnLayout/AF_2columnLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is also using a negative margin on the image. But it works only if you place the first image in the second container and if you know the height of the image. So for your example it's fine, but it's not a solution that fits all possibilities.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    [TEXT]
</div>

<div>
    <img src="[URL]" alt="[ALT]">
    [TEXT]
</div>
```

**CSS**

The `height`, `width` and `margin` values are just example values.

```
div {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
    padding: 250px 0 0 0;
}

img {
    float: left;        
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -320px;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/8Kd4g/)

Comment: Thanks for the negative margin suggestion. I'm trying to apply it, but without success.

I'm including a link to the code I'm using, as well as a new image better explaining what I've been asked to do.

http://unfetteredletters.com/webdev/twocolumnlayout.jpg

http://unfetteredletters.com/webdev/AF_columnLayout/AF_2columnLayout.html